# Is there anything special about the “Utilities” folder?

Tags: macos, folders

I download a third party app, e.g., [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com). Since I think of it as a utility, not an normal application, I want to put it in the `/Applications/Utilities` folder. I notice that I'm asked to authenticate to do this differently than I would be if I put it in [/Applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62847/is-there-anything-special-about-the-applications-folder). What, if anything, is special about `/Applications/Utilities`?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is really 'special' about that folder. It's just a folder in /Applications like any other folder (albeit with a custom icon). The permissions on the folder should be the same as /Applications itself — if they're not, they've probably been changed. You should be able to fix the permissions with a permissions repair from Disk Utility.